# Content Type or InfoPath? that is the question!

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, infopath, sharepoint-addin, content-type

I have a list in SharePoint 2013 where people add activities. These activities come in different types (e.g. Event, Tradeshow, Advert etc...) and the fields required for each type is varies slightly. There is a set number of fields all activities use and then there are additional fields that are specific for each Activity type.

I am familiar with both using InfoPath to create the forms and using form logic to hide fields depending on the type selected and I am also familiar with setting up multiple Content Types and using a different content type for each activity.

Both seem suitable options but I am wondering if I am missing something?

Is there a preffered method for this type of scenario or am I really in a grey area between the two and it's more preference?

Answer (score 1):

Been advised on other sites to use Content Types (CT's) wherever possible, InfoPath form editing is great but the power is from the CT's and they will be retained moving forward.